# Unable to send multiple templates as pdf in an email - VF template

Tags: apex, after-trigger, vf-email-template

I have WorkOrder, WorkOrderLineItem and Product2 object. In trigger when WorkOrder Status will become completed, i am checking if tht WorkOrder contains specific 2 type of products. If it is present i am trying to send email with vf template as pdf attachment.

The issue here is

- I am receiving 2 emails with both the templates as attached. Is there any way where i can get both the templates in one email.
- The templates don't have any data into them. Basically blank fields.

I tried diplaying those in vf page render as pdf, both are working fine. But when i am using it in trigger i am not getting any values.

VF Template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test Subject" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="WorkOrderLineItem">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody > 
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    <messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf">
         <c:test1 wId="{!relatedTo.WorkOrderId}"/>
    </messaging:attachment>
    <messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf">
         <c:test2 wId="{!relatedTo.WorkOrderId}"/>
    </messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Trigger (after Update)

```
private void sendCertificate() {
        Set<Id> wkId = new Set<Id>();
        Set<String> pCode = new Set<String>{'A','B'};
            EmailTemplate et=[SELECT Id, DeveloperName , body,IsActive FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Test_Template'];
        for (WorkOrder wo : lstNewWorkOrders) {
            WorkOrder oldRec = mapOldWorkOrders.get(wo.Id);
            if(oldRec.Status != wo.Status && (wo.Status == 'Completed')) {
                wkId.add(wo.Id);
            }
        }

        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstsemail = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(WorkOrderLineItem wli : [SELECT Id, WorkOrderLineItem.WorkOrder.ContactId FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE WorkOrderId IN :wkId AND Product2.ProductCode IN :pCode]) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage semail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            semail.setTemplateId(et.Id); 
            semail.setTargetObjectId(wli.WorkOrder.ContactId);
            semail.setWhatId(wli.WorkOrderId);
            semail.setSenderDisplayName('Test Email'); 
            semail.setUseSignature(false); 
            semail.setBccSender(false); 
            semail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            lstsemail.add(semail);
        }
        if (!lstsemail.isEmpty()) {
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] r = Messaging.sendEmail(lstsemail);
        }
    }
```

VF Component

```
<apex:component layout="none" access="global" controller="sanicerticontroller">
    <apex:attribute name="wId" description="Record Id" type="id" assignTo="{!record_Id}"/> 

    <body>
                <p style="font-size:20px;">{!accName}</p>
                 <p style="font-size:20px;">{!address}</p>
    </body>
</apex:component>
```

VF COmponent Controller

```
public class sanicerticontroller {
    public Integer day{get;set;}
    public String month{get;set;}
    public String address{get;set;}
    public Integer year{get;set;}
    public String accName{get;set;}
    public List<WorkOrderLineItem> woOLI{get;set;}
    public List<String> datewrap{get;set;}
    public Id record_Id;
    
    public Id getrecord_Id() {
        return this.record_Id;
    }
    public void setrecord_Id(String argId){
    
        woOLI = new List<WorkOrderLineItem>();
        if(this.record_Id == null) {
            record_Id = argId;  
            woOLI = [SELECT Id, Product2.ProductCode, WorkOrderId, WorkOrder.AccountId, WorkOrder.Account.Name, WorkOrder.Account.ShippingCountry, WorkOrder.Account.ShippingState, 
                     WorkOrder.Account.ShippingStreet, WorkOrder.Account.ShippingPostalCode, WorkOrder.LastModifiedDate 
                     FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE WorkOrderId =:record_Id];
            system.debug('@@@@woOLI' + woOLI);
            if(!woOLI.isEmpty() && woOLI !=null) {
                for(WorkOrderLineItem jj: woOLI) {
                    accName = jj.WorkOrder.Account.Name;
                    address = jj.WorkOrder.Account.ShippingStreet + ' ' + jj.WorkOrder.Account.ShippingPostalCode;
                    datewrap.add(String.valueof(jj.WorkOrder.LastModifiedDate.Day()));
                    datewrap.add(String.valueof(jj.WorkOrder.LastModifiedDate.format('MMMM')));
                    datewrap.add(String.valueof( jj.WorkOrder.LastModifiedDate.Year()));      
                }
            }
        }else{
        }
    } 
    
    public sanicerticontroller() {
        datewrap = new List<String>{'','',''};
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, `if(!woOLI.isEmpty() && woOLI !=null) {` is the incorrect way to check for potentially empty list (null first, empty second). Queries always return a list, never a null list, and it is always okay to iterate over an empty list, so you don't need this if statement at all.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox.. Can you please provide me some idea how to manage to get both the templates as pdf in one email . Currently if i am having 2 records , email is coming twice with both the templates. Can we render both the vf components inside the vf template on condition ?